# Capturing traffic on my local home network

Tags: wireshark

Since I changed the firmware of my router for security I haven't been able to capture traffic with Wireshark. I think the reason is that I have a subnet by default.

How can I capture all the traffic from all the devices through my local home network?

Comment: You can capture subnet traffic with Wireshark (https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureFilters)  .You can also capture subnet traffic with CommView (Tamosoft). I use CommView.

Comment: how did you capture before the change ?  port mirroring ? what is the firmware of you router ?

Comment: so this is complicated on modern switched traffic, because you can only see north-south traffic, but no east-west (you can see stuff going in and out of the router, but traffic from box to box inside the network is hard to track). generally speaking the correct solution is to buy switches smart enough to use port-mirroring, and pipe that to an endpoint configured as an IDPS/SIM/SEIM

Comment: Hi, thanks for your responses. Well CommView looks quite nice I'm thinking on buying it. he thing is even though I have created and added devices to the each subnet (in relation with the device type) the devices do not appear on the subnets where I included them. They all appear on subnet number 1. Why is this?, my question